# RTL(Persian-Arabic)Letters Messed up in android studio editor

Tags: windows, macos, android-studio, editor

In AndroidStudio editor when i select part of a Persian text or RTL language(Persian-Arabic)Letters ,it Messed up.

for example this part of code :

```
   <string name="NetworkConnection">لطفا اتصال اینترنت خود را بررسی نمایید.</string>
```

But in editor after select part of RTL sentence reshape to this form :

[image]

i need to install a plugin or another solution there are?

---

**Edit 1 , Answer :**

For `Windows OS` users , said responses work correctly.

But for `Mac OS` users , according [tools.android.com document](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration) by below path in `AndroidStudio` select **`Edit Custom Properties`**

[image]

By this , you make `idea.properties` file in `~/Library/Preferences/{FOLDER_NAME}/idea.properties` path that you can edit this file and add your properties like `editor.new.rendering=true` for `RTL Support` in `AndroidStudio` editor.

Comment: Don't worry. It does that on every RTL language. Also on my computer. It's more important how it is displayed on your device than how it displayed on your computer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a Reported Bug in Android Studio.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57667

And according to the comment #19 and #21 this issue is about to solve in Android Studio 2.0 stable release (soon):

comment #19:

> Release in Android Studio 2.0. set "editor.new.rendering=true" in in
>   idea.properties as described in
>   http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration
>
> Not turned on by default in IntelliJ 15, but user configurable.

comment #20:

> I've added an example for how to configure it in
>   http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration
>
> This is not going to be a user configurable option; we plan to enable
>   it by default as soon as we've tested it and confirmed that its
>   performance and stability is satisfactory.

Comment: The more relevant issue is https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=182739

Answer (score 3):

For Android Studio 1.5 in Windows create file with name "idea.properties" in
C:\Users\ your_user_name_folder \ .AndroidStudio1.5
and write this in the file:

```
editor.new.rendering=true
```

I tested it and it works.
[image: persian character selection]

Answer (score 2):

Salaam saeed 
I find a way,  it has already some errors, but better than nothing(kachi baazi hichi!!)
File > settings > Editor >colors&font> font 
save a copy of the scheme , then uncheck the show monospace choice, then select Tahoma font. this work makes it better but not excellent.

 my farsi is so better than English!!

خلاصه بهت بگم که فونت تاهوما رو انتخاب کن

Comment: Read guidelines  and  edit you answer to make it better.

Comment: there was no Tahoma, but i changed the font. at least android studio now shows farsi better, not perfect.

Comment: :-)) :-))))))))))

Answer (score 1):

currently Android Studio does NOT give a good support on RTL languages.
But you can update your Android Studio to the latest version on "Stable Channel", this version somehow provides a good support for RTL languages.

Also, Android Studio has a editor for its resource files. It is completely usable for RTL languages. In your resource file click on the "open editor" on the upper right corner of the screen to enter the editor.

Comment: I am using the latest version of `Android Studio` - But about editor : Right! but still not very good

Comment: are you sure you are on "stable channel" not for example the canary or beta channel?

Answer (score 0):

I`m using android studio version 2.1.1 and yet there are lots of problems with persian. when U type persian, in xml it shows reverse. but there is no problem in final apk and my device shows it correctly.
and if u want to use persian fonts use it this way:

```
TextView tx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
Typeface custom_font_BKoodakBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),                
        "fonts/B Koodak Bold.ttf");
 if (tx != null) {
        tx.setTypeface(custom_font_BKoodakBold);
```

I used it and it works perfect, of curse in device. textView in R.id.textView is my text written in xml and BKoodakBold is my font.

سلام
وقتی در اندروید استودیو به فارسی تایپ کنی لغات درست اما جمله برعکسه. اما زمانی که برنامه رو در موبایل اجرا کنی این مشکل خودشو نشون نمیده و جای نگرانی نداره. 
برای تعیین فونت هم کدهای مربوطه به صورت زیره:

```
TextView tx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
Typeface custom_font_BKoodakBold = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), 
        "fonts/B Koodak Bold.ttf");
 if (tx != null) {
        tx.setTypeface(custom_font_BKoodakBold);
```

این روش تا الان که برای من به خوبی کار کرده. ورژن اندروید استودیو من 2.1.1 است.
 نوشته من در فایل ایکس ام ال به نام تکست ویو است. ببخشید به انگلیسی ننوشتم چون جمله اشتباه تایپ میشه.
امیدوارم موفق باشی و البته این مطلب خیلی دیر نشده باشه